# how to make different button using repeater?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

i'm trying to have different button(different text and icon) with repeater in qml using this code:
when i try to add image property in ListElement i discovered that i could not

```
Main.qml 

    
    //green text for my group members
    
    
    ApplicationWindow{
        id: applicationWindow
        property string displayedButton: ""
        width: 800
        height: 380
        visible: true
     Page {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:page
        ListModel{
               id: fruitModel
    
               ListElement {
    
                   name: "CLIM"
    
               }
               ListElement {
                   name: "Kiwi"
                   colorValue: "sienna"
               }
               ListElement {
                   name: "Banana"
                   colorValue: "gold"
               }
           }
    
        GridLayout {
            id:rec
            anchors.fill: parent
    
    
           ColumnLayout {
    
                anchors.topMargin: 20
                y:10
                id: leftMenuBar
                Layout.preferredWidth: 90
                Layout.fillHeight: true
    
                clip: true
                spacing: 10
                Repeater{
                    model: fruitModel
                    delegate: Button{
                        implicitHeight: 90
                        implicitWidth: 90
    
                        onClicked: displayedButton = text
                        id: delegateRoot
    
                                       required property string name
                                       required property color colorValue
    
                                       text: delegateRoot.name
    
    
    
    
    
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                    }
                }
    
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
                Layout.leftMargin: 13
            }
    
            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
    
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 12
                    border.width: 2
                    border.color: "lightgray"
                    radius: 35
    
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }
    
            // Placeholder item to align footer buttons
    
        }
    
    //footerbutton
        footer:RowLayout {
            width: 500
            spacing:12
            Item {
            implicitWidth: 3
            }
    
            Repeater {
                Item {
    
                }
                model: 8
    
                delegate: Button{
                    implicitHeight: 90
                    implicitWidth: 90
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text
    
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i'm using stackoverflow to learn qml and your suggestions really help me

Comment: You have a property named `model` which you should feed with your different parameters. Then, use those parameters in your delegate. Just read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html)!

Answer (score 2):

First, you should populate your `ListModel`/`ListElement` with your icon setting. I choose to supply icon assets in SVG. Then you can consider rendering them using the `Button.icon`:

```
       //..
        ListModel{
            id: fruitModel
            ListElement {
                name: "CLIM"
                col: "blue"
                pic: "cloud.svg"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Kiwi"
                col: "sienna"
                pic: "smile.svg"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Banana"
                col: "gold"
                pic: "banana.svg"
            }
        }
        //...
        ColumnLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: fruitModel
                delegate: Button {
                    implicitHeight: 90
                    implicitWidth: 90
                    icon.source: pic
                    icon.color: col
                    icon.width: 32
                    icon.height: 32
                    Text {
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
                        text: name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)